# Setting a delay between methods in c#

Tags: c#, delay

I'm trying to run four methods, but between each time a method runs, I want the program to wait a second. Here's the code, I really have no idea how to go about this, thank you in advance!

```
private void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    {
        while (GlobalVar.Direction == "down")
        { movedown();}
        while (GlobalVar.Direction == "up")
        {moveup();}
        while (GlobalVar.Direction == "right")
        {moveright();}
        while (GlobalVar.Direction == "left")
        {moveleft();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the whole app hang during that delay or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your method `async` and use `await Task.Delay(1000)`

Like this:

```
private async void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    {
        while (GlobalVar.Direction == "down")
        {  
           await Task.Delay(1000); 
           movedown();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Requires .Net 4.5, but should be fine for any new projects.

Comment: This works great thank you, can you explain what 'async' is please?

Comment: @LucasHolmes you can read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @LucasHolmes, basically your method running asynchronously therefore your window doesn't freeze.with await, it doesn't go to the nextline,wait for one second (1000 millisecond) and then calling your movedown method

Answer (score 0):

To introduce a delay of one second, use the following call:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The "1000" refers to 1000 milliseconds or one second.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to (or can't) use `async` you can have add your methods to "script" and have timer pick up one step at a time. I.e. using [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) code would look similar to following (untested) code:

```
var script = new Queue<Action>();
script.Enqueue( movedown);
script.Enqueue( moveup);

var timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += (s,e)=> 
  {
    if (script.Count > 0)
    {
       script.Dequeue()();
    }
    else 
    {
       timer.Enabled = false; 
    } 
  };
timer.Enabled = true;
```